# Google Maps for cycling

Tags: maps

I would like to understand how to find cyclist friendly paths in London using Google Maps on my Windows 10 PC. I can do this using my Android phone, there is an option that shows me such paths in the google map app. These paths are shown in green. However, when I just go to  https://www.google.com/maps on my Windows 10 PC I don't see a setting that would highlight such paths. In fact google maps will propose me a cyclist path (or several paths) between any two points, but I will not be able to see which bits of this path are cyclist friendly and which are not. Such bits would be shown in green on my android app.

So is there some way to see these "green paths" on my Windows PC?

Comment: Google Maps is IMO not the best when it comes to finding cycle paths. Have you tried https://www.opencyclemap.org ? While it doesn't have all the options (such as routing) that GM offers, it gives a pretty good overview.

Comment: Thanks Berend! No I did not know about opencyclemap.org . Indeed, it looks pretty good

Comment: I gave you an answer that tells you how to turn on bicycling mode in Google Maps. I recommend Strava's routing function as it offers a heatmap of where cyclists ride and routes according to where is most popular. Unfortunately you now need to subscribe to use that feature.

Comment: Argenti, thanks a lot for both recommendations! What is Strava, and how to subscribe to it?

Comment: As usual with these questions I have to recommend http://brouter.de/brouter-web/ . It’s a great routing tool for planning routes at home and there is also an android version (to be used in combination with Osmand).

Comment: cyclestreets.net uses openstreetmap data and routing and even though Google is catching up, it's still very poor in comparison. I'd recommend an OSM-based solution. (I'm a London-based cyclist)

Comment: The look of Google Maps is is really vrap. Although https://en.mapy.cz is originally a Czech service, it uses the Openstreetmap elsewhere and has a darn good planer, IMO. And the outdpor maps look much much better. And it is free, Strava is pretty expensive. Before strava, I woul try Komoot, that pne also has free options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you see a very different Google Maps in the UK than I see in the US:

[image]

Comment: That's amazing! Huge thanks, it turns out that this works in the UK as well :)

Comment: I tried this out in the Netherlands. Be careful, it does not show a lot of roads which are bike friendly, but it does show a lot of paths in a national park which are walking only. (Although I have to admit that before some time in the mornings, cycling on some/most of those paths may be allowed, they are not cycle paths.)